# In Microsoft Word VBA, how do I check for repagination?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using Microsoft Word 2007.  I open up some document with VBA and I need to do some work on them.  However when a file is just opened, VBA do this repagination and doesn't wait for it to finish before continuing.  So what would happen is that my code would then error because it think the opened document is only a few pages long when it's much longer.

My Code:

```
Documents.Open fileName:="C:\file.doc", Visible:=False
MsgBox ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Number of Pages")
```

I have tried to use sleep but it doesn't work, any ideas?

Comment: Ok so I found a work around.  I haven't tried Nick's answer down bellow which look pretty legit.  In anycase what I did was to loop through the entire document one paragraph at a time.  It's less efficient but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim NewDoc As Document
Dim PageCount As Long

Set NewDoc = fileName:="C:\file.doc", Visible:=False
PageCount = NewDoc.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)

MsgBox PageCount
```